# Runtime Error 13 : Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time coding from scratch and a very dumb question indeed.

Why do i keep getting this error?

> Runtime Error '13' : Type mismatch

My value in B1 is an integer

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
xdate = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
lsdate = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)
'MsgBox lsdate
If Day(lsdate) > Day(xdate) Then
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range ("B1") * 1 = result
Else
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range ("B1") * 1.07 = result
End If
Range("c1").Value = result
End Sub
```

I have further edit my code to the following but not able to get the condition to work

```
'To create the following condition
'If less than 7 days interest = 0%
'if 8 to 30 days interest = 7%
'if more than 31 days interest = 9%

Sub Workbook_Open()

For i = 1 To 3 'Rows.Count
xdate = Cells(i, 1)
'MsgBox Cells(i, 1)
nulldate = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)
irate7late = DateAdd("d", -8, Date)
irate7early = DateAdd("d", -30, Date)


If Day(nulldate) < Day(xdate) Then
    result = Cells(i, 2) * 1
ElseIf Day(irate7early) <= Day(xdate) And Day(xdate) <= Day(irate7late) Then
            '30/9/2015      20/10/2015      20/10/2015      22/10/2015
    result = Cells(i, 2) * 1.07

ElseIf Day(irate7early) > Day(xdate) Then
    result = Cells(i, 2) * 1.09
End If

Cells(i, 3).Value = result

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You seem pretty new at programming, so I'll explain plainly :

When you are trying to assign a `value` to a `variable` in almost every language, you use :

```
variable = value
```

So you can do a lot of operations on the `value`, which is on the right of the equals `=`.

BUT you canNOT do operations on the left of the equals `=` when you simply assigning a `value` to a `variable`. You can do almost any operations when you are testing 2 `variables` but you'll have a keyword like `If` or `While` at the start of the line of code.

---

So the issue with your code is that you reversed the order of the `value` and the `variable` and tried to do `value * 1 = variable`

Here is your corrected code (I indented it so that it can be read easily) :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
xdate = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
lsdate = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)
'MsgBox lsdate
If Day(lsdate) > Day(xdate) Then
   result = Worksheets("sheet1").Range ("B1") * 1
Else
   result = Worksheets("sheet1").Range ("B1") * 1.07
End If

Sheets("Sheet_name").Range("c1").Value = result

End Sub
```

And you should always reference the sheet you are working with, because previously, your code didn't specify on which sheet the `C1` was supposed to be.

So here, just change `Sheet_name` to whatever the name of your sheet is!

Answer (score 0):

variables need to get the values from sheet. You are trying opposite way which is why you getting error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
xdate = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
lsdate = DateAdd("d", -7, Date)
'MsgBox lsdate
If Day(lsdate) > Day(xdate) Then
result = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1") * 1
Else
result = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1") * 1.07
End If
Range("c1").Value = result
End Sub


Sub test1()

Dim var1 As Variant

' If you need to get values from the range("D1") Then use the below code
var1 = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D1").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi newjenn, could you enlighten me ? I am getting most of my variables from my sheet except B1 * 1

Comment: @JunYi

' If you need to get values from the range("D1") Then use the above code